# emacs: kill-line doesn't append to kill ring

Tags: emacs, copy-paste

I've noticed that the behavior of kill-region and yank in my emacs setup seems to have changed.

If I highlight a region and `kill-region` (or even just `kill-line`) and then `yank` it, I get some older kill. I have tried browsing the kill ring and I see that the killed text is never even saved to the kill ring.

Any thought on how to debug this change in behavior?

Comment: I'm still not sure what triggers this behavior, but the problem is more succinctly stated as: `kill-line` function doesn't append to kill-ring.

Comment: I don't understand that by looking at a developer build of Emacs Trunk.  In the developer build, `kill-line` uses `kill-region`, which uses `kill-append` / `kill-new` / `copy-region-as-kill`.  Go ahead and up up your source code for `simple.el` and see if you have the same thing.  What would make a difference is using `delete-region` -- so perhaps you have a custom function somewhere that uses `delete-region` instead of `kill-region`.

Comment: When you experience behavior that doesn't make sense, it is usually a good idea to try running Emacs without loading anything extra -- i.e., a blank / empty `.emacs` file.  If you still experience the same problem with a blank / empty `.emacs` file, then you know it's not a problem with additional libraries and additional user configurations.  If you are using an older version of Emacs, back-up your installation and try out the latest public release or even a developer build snapshot of the future public release.

Comment: +1 to @lawlist's last comment. You don't say whether you see the problem when starting with `emacs -Q`. If not, then recursively bisect your init file to find out what you are doing that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this question. As mentioned by @lawlist and @Drew, it was due to some interaction between go-mode and volatile-highlights.

For more info, see https://github.com/dominikh/go-mode.el/issues/53.